# SQL Server Row_number in ORDER BY CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, case, row-number

EDITED THE WHOLE TOPIC.

I need to create a view that sort article per type.

1. If I only have the type : *VALUE -> I need to show this line  only.
2. If I have the type : *VALUE & 2 -> Still showing row accordingly to *VALUE type only.
3. If I only have the type : 2 -> Showing this one.

I already did somethink like this :

VALUE* is a value that should come from an another table with a Join.

`SELECT Id_item ,Name_item , Type_item , Id_type_item FROM ITEM 
WHERE Name_item = 'Gillette' AND (Id_Type_item = VALUE* OR Id_Type_item ='10')

ORDER BY CASE 
             WHEN row_number() OVER(ORDER BY Id_item DESC , Id_Type_Item DESC) <= 1 THEN 0 
             ELSE 1 
         END;`

But it does that in the case where we've got both row for the types(*VALUE & 10):

```
Id_item / Name_item / Type_item / Id_Type_Item
1       Gillette    45            30 (*VALUE)
1       Gillette    2             10
```

So I think that the order by on the Over() could be useful to always sort by *VALUE (which are in reality another column from another table)

I always want to select 1 row of data only ! :)

Comment: Use the function ROW_NUMBER() to create a ranking from 1 onwards with the order you want. Or TOP 1 with a proper ORDER BY.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a DENSE_RANK() over your var field.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Comment: You want a single row from the first Select returning a result? Are those Selects actually accessing different tables?

Comment: Neither your query nor your explanation makes any sense. You will need to post sample data (this is the third request). Otherwise no one will be able to make sense of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, that what you want is the "first" row returned from each `SELECT`? There's no need to use a separate `SELECT` statement for each variable on the same table, you can use a window function to do so. I believe this is what you might be after.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    --The following assumes table A and B have the same DDL (which begs the question, why are they different tables?)
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var
                              ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --Replace SELECT(NULL) with your actual ordering criteria
    FROM A
    WHERE var IN (1,2)
    UNION --ALL(?)
    SELECT *
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var
                              ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --Replace SELECT(NULL) with your actual ordering criteria
    FROM B
    WHERE var IN (3))
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: I want to select the unique raw there is for one of the case in the priority 1>2>3.
Thanks for your quick answer too :)

EDIT : Not the 1st raw of each select but the 1st raw on every select I did.

Comment: @Rurirm I don't understand what you mean there. Sample data and expected results, like Yogesh asked for, would be helpful.

Comment: @Rurirm and what is a "raw"?

Comment: I want to read information that changes in function of 'var'.

For example , I wanna read every information of a car as I put the car brand in the 'where' of the 'view'. And I want to prioritize information when the cartype is 1/2/3 and in this order 1>2>3
EDIT : I mean 'row'

Comment: @Rurirm post the sample data we keep asking for, please.#

Comment: I can't it's some sensitive data ^^'

Comment: I said **sample** data, not actual data.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tiwvadV , as you can see , I could have multiple car type per car , but I want to take the name of the type for a car that have in priority the car_type_id as 1 , if null > 2 , if null >3 @Larnu

Comment: @Rurirm Don't post an image... I haven't look at it, as it's not helpful. Post your data as **text** by [**editting**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50700863/edit) your question.

Comment: changed the post as it should be quite more understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. In this case ROW_NUMBER, RANK and DENSE_RANK would all work. However, ROW_COUNT is not a valid window function in sql server.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE(ID INT, Value INT)
DECLARE @B TABLE(ID INT,Value INT)
INSERT INTO @A VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,2),(6,1),(7,3)
INSERT INTO @B VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,3),(6,2),(7,1),(8,3)

;WITH D AS
(
    SELECT ID,Value FROM @A WHERE Value IN(1,2)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,Value FROM @B WHERE Value IN (3)
 )
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
      ID, Value,
      ValueRankInSet = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY ID) -- <-- If you do not have an ID field you can subst ID with NEWID() as order is not important 
    FROM D
)AS X
WHERE ValueRankInSet = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the priority within your Select(s) and then order by it in the row_number:

```
with cte as 
 (
    SELECT *,
       row_number()
       over (-- partition by ??? 
             order by prio) as Position
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT 1 as prio, * FROM A WHERE var = 1
    UNION -- probably a more efficient UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as prio, * FROM A WHERE var = 2
    UNION -- probably a more efficient UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 as prio, * FROM B WHERE var = 3
    )
 )
select *
from cte
WHERE Position = 1
```

Comment: I really like your solution ;)

Comment: @dnoeth The 'partition by' clause is pertinent when you want to group multiple row  ?

Comment: @MJH I can't cause I don't have the reputation yet xD (limited to 15)

Comment: `partition by` is similar to `group by` for aggregates

Comment: @Rurirm:  You need to ask some better questions then.  :)

Comment: @Rurirm: You can *accept* it if it solves your problem

Comment: With your solution it will does : 
Prio :  /  Position / request result :
1      /      1  
               2  
              3
2            1
3            1
              2
So the SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE POSITION = 1 will display the value for prio 1 / 1 & prio 2/1 & prio 3/1 right ?
I want to display 1/1 , but if it doesn't exist : 2/1 and then if it doesn't exist 3/1

Comment: or does it makes it like Prio = 1 and Pos = 1 , 2 / Prio = 2 and Pos = 3 ,4 ,5 ,6 /  Pos = 3 Prio = 7

Comment: My Select (without PARTITION BY) will return exactly one row: the row with prio 1, if this doesn't exist, prio 2, if this doesn't exist, prio 3, simply try it